# Error - Using babel.node for start script when deploying on heroku - what to do in production?

Tags: heroku, deployment, babeljs, production, babel-node

When deploying on heroku, Im getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node server/app.js --presets es2015,stage-2
```

My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "babel-node server.js --presets es2015,stage-2",
        "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
        "build": "webpack -p",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
 "dependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
        "express": "^4.15.3",
        "morgan": "^1.8.2",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "pg": "^7.0.2",
        "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
        "sequelize": "^4.4.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
        "react-router": "^4.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
        "webpack": "^3.4.1"
      }
```

I found a post that suggests putting babel.cli into dependencies, not into dev dependencies but that doesn't work. Anyone has an idea?
Thanks!